# combine two queries where one is querying the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I want to combine these two queries I am thinking a self-join but not sure

Query 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT SalesHierachy.RegionCode, SalesHierachy.RegionName, 
Left([RegionCode],5) AS Expr1
FROM SalesHierachy
GROUP BY SalesHierachy.RegionCode, SalesHierachy.RegionName,  Left([RegionCode],5)
ORDER BY SalesHierachy.RegionCode;
```

Query 2

```
SELECT Query1.Expr1
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.Expr1
HAVING Count(Query1.Expr1)>=2;
```

Comment: Would help if you actually mention what you're trying to achieve in your result.

Comment: SELECT fields FROM(SELECT fields FROM inner query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Query1 inside Query2

```
SELECT Query1.Expr1
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT SalesHierachy.RegionCode, SalesHierachy.RegionName, 
    Left([RegionCode],5) AS Expr1
    FROM SalesHierachy
    GROUP BY 
    SalesHierachy.RegionCode, SalesHierachy.RegionName,  left([RegionCode],5)
) as T1
GROUP BY Query1.Expr1
HAVING Count(Query1.Expr1)>=2;
```